# Expand WP Theme Search Field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress theme that allows managing different properties. For locations property has different meta fields for location - Country, State, City, Neighborhood (whatever this is).

The theme offers the ability to search by each of these locations but doesn't offer an ability to enable a search across all of these meta fields simultaneously.

Question is, is it possible for me to take any of these search fields and expand it somehow so that the query checks for keywords in all meta fields including the post title? How can I do it myself. The theme author seems to be overwhelmed with other things.

Comment: You could override the function by calling `pre_get_posts`, maybe lookup the query that generates the request, copy/paste the necessary code and modify the query itself. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts